# Trouble deploying static site using Gitlab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm currently developing a project containing an Angular SPA Frontend Repo and a nodeJS backend repo.
I've been looking into ways, how to deploy my Applications to RHEL/centOS using Gitlab-CI after compiling/minifying my project.
The problem is, I can't figure out, how to use eg. the YUI Compressor for shrinking within the gitlab-ci.yml file.
I also have trouble to use eg SSH to deploy my files into my Public Folder on my webserver or to trigger pm2 to reload the application.
I'd love to implement a basic unit testing in this approach, but I still can't get the hang of how it's done either.
I'd be glad to hear any suggestions from you that could expand my knownledge.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using yuicompressor as a jar, how about writing this in .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
build:
  script:
  - yuicompressor.sh
```

Make sure you have a shell script in  your path, which `chmod +x` bit set that does this:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar /path/to/your/yuicompressor-x.y.z.jar
```

That file must be on your runner vm called yuicompressor.sh. It doesn't seem good to me to hard-code paths to resources on your runners into .gitlab-ci.yml.

Note you might need different args to the java app.

I put all executable tools (mostly scripts) that my runners need into a folder `/glrunner/tools` and place `/glrunner/tools` into the PATH of my runner when I start it.

If you're having trouble because you're using Dockerized runners, get everything working OUTSIDE docker with a shell runner on a Linux  VM, and later move to containers.  This is the number one rookie mistake people make.

Once you're using containers and you have a Dockerfile to bring up your tooling, perhaps you won't need to consider static "tool/script" folders like I have initially suggested, but it's a good way to get started, learn Gitlab CI Runners first, then learn Docker.